# Reverse the scale coloring in image.plot

Tags: r

I am using image.plot for displaying a climatalogical value (calles SPEI) of Germany.
Here is my image.plot code:

```
image.plot(lon.list[[1]], lat.list[[1]], spei3.list[[4]][,,315],
           main = "SPEI Germany",
           xlab = "Longitude",
           ylab = "Latitude",
           legend.lab = "SPEI",
           legend.line = 2.5,
           zlim = c(-3.0,3.0))
plot(sf_object, add = T, border = "Black")
```

This is the outcome:
[image]

It looks quite ok, I just need the low values to be red since they represent dryness and the high values to be blue as they represent wetness. So I actually just need to reverse the scale coloring and it would be done. There were quite a few things I tried but nothing brought me to a satisfying solution.

I hope it is possible to solve this also without sample code and data since I believe it is a quite genreal question.

Anybody with an idea?

EDIT:
This is the new plot after the modification suggested by Sandwichnick:
[image]

As you can see the scale colors are totally different now. They were just supposed to be reversed.

LAST EDIT:
I found a solution for this. In short: you create a few color palettes, maybe additionally by different packages like `RColorBrewer` or `randomcoloR` and pick the codes of the colors you need and put them in a vector. This vector is then given as the `col` argument to `image.plot`.

See here:

```
# set the color palette
SPI.col <- c("#0000FFFF", "#0066FFFF", "#00CCFFFF", "#00FFCCFF", "#00FF00FF", "#FF6600FF", "#FF0000FF")
image.plot(lon.list[[1]], lat.list[[1]], Index.list[[1]][[1]][,,211], 
           main = paste0(Indices[1], "-3 Germany ", models[1]),
           col = rev(SPI.col),
           xlab = "Longitude",
           ylab = "Latitude",
           legend.lab = "SPEI",
           legend.line = 2.5,
           zlim = c(-3.0,3.0))
plot(sf_object, add = T, border = "Black")
```

This leads to the following map plot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which package you are using, but im guessing `fields`:

try:

```
image.plot(lon.list[[1]], lat.list[[1]], spei3.list[[4]][,,315],
           #this is the changed part
           col=hcl.colors(64, "Temps", rev = FALSE),
           #end change
           main = "SPEI Germany",
           xlab = "Longitude",
           ylab = "Latitude",
           legend.lab = "SPEI",
           legend.line = 2.5,
           zlim = c(-3.0,3.0))
```

more on the possible color palletes:
[https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/04/01/hcl-based-color-palettes-in-grdevices/`](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/04/01/hcl-based-color-palettes-in-grdevices/%60)

As you  cannot use hcl, I would like to try something. HCL color palettes are nothing more than a string vector containging the color space as RGB-HEX values.

If I put `dput(hcl.colors(64, "Temps", rev = FALSE))` (I generate the vector to be printed on the console) and give the result to you to put into `col`, it might work.

Try putting the following vector in your `col` parameter:

```r
c("#089392", "#039692", "#019A92", "#029D92", "#08A091", "#10A491", 
"#19A790", "#22AA8F", "#2AAD8E", "#33B08D", "#3CB38C", "#44B68A", 
"#4CB989", "#55BB87", "#5DBE85", "#66C184", "#6FC382", "#79C582", 
"#82C782", "#8CC982", "#94CB83", "#9DCD84", "#A5CF85", "#ADD186", 
"#B4D388", "#BCD58A", "#C3D78C", "#CBD98E", "#D2DB91", "#D9DD94", 
"#E0DF97", "#E7E19A", "#EAE09A", "#EADC95", "#EAD890", "#EAD48B", 
"#EACF87", "#EACB83", "#EAC77F", "#EAC37B", "#EABF78", "#EABA75", 
"#EAB672", "#EAB26F", "#E9AD6D", "#E9A96C", "#E9A46A", "#E9A069", 
"#E89B69", "#E89768", "#E79268", "#E78D69", "#E6886A", "#E5846A", 
"#E57F6C", "#E47A6D", "#E3756F", "#E27070", "#E06B73", "#DD6775", 
"#DA6478", "#D6607A", "#D35D7C", "#CF597E")
```

you could generate the vectors for the pallets by using (https://rdrr.io/snippets/)

## EDIT:

I do not know which colors R is using in your example. Check the documentation(help) of your `image.plot` or `image`  function and look for the default `col` parameter. This might be different in your Version.
This is how it looks in my RStudio:
[image: Look in ## Default S3 method. Which value is given for col?]
Look in ## Default S3 method. Which value is given for `col`?

### Reverse col

There are two possibilities to reverse `col`

#### 1.Possibility

If the value for col has a Parameter named `rev` or `reverse`, just switch it from its default value (From `TRUE` to `FALSE` in my case):
`hcl.colors(12, "YlOrRd", rev = FALSE)`

Then put this in the `col` param of your `image.plot`

#### 2. Possibility

In the case where there is no `rev` in the color-scheme default.
You copy the parameter and reverse it using the `rev()`-function (`my_col_param <- rev(hcl.colors(12, "YlOrRd", rev = TRUE))` in the case of my default value). Put this in the declaration of `image.plot()`: `image.plot(..., col= rev(my_col_param))`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, I am using the ```fields``` package. Unfortunately ```hcl.colors()``` does not seem to work at my machine. Most likely because it is still R version 3.5.2. I am working on Linux and still have to figure out, how to to the upgrade to version 3.6 which is needed here.

Comment: Maybe my edit might be useful. It is a bit hacky but it could work

Comment: Thanks again for your effort and creativity. It seems like it has done the job it was supposed to do. But the outcome is still not what I want. See the new plot above.

Comment: I edited my answer. I unfortunately do not know which palette your R is using by default. Try my edit. Alterantively you can try to generate the "spectral" palette using my described vectorization technique with `dput`. Replace `"Temps"` with `"spectral"`. It looks at least similiar to your colours

Comment: Thanks for efforts @Sandwichnick. After all I found a solution, inspired by this YT-Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ziZeBH3Pe1E

I will show it above.